# Socket.io fails to emit messages to Node server on Chrome & Firefox

Tags: firefox, node.js, google-chrome, websocket, socket.io

I'm trying to figure out what is wrong with my code / settings for a while now.Basically I want to send a message from the client to the server. The following works in all browsers **except** FF(11) and chrome(18.0.1025.152 m).

Here is some info:

1. I run Node.js on Windows 7 enterprise 64-bit machine
2. I use apache to serve the page from localhost
3. I'm listening on port 8080 with socket.io
4. It looks like chrome and FF fallback to xhr-polling / jsonp-polling instead of using sockets
5. I can push messages from the server, but I can't emit from the client

Server code:

```
var io = require('C:/Users/shlomis/node_modules/socket.io/lib/socket.io').listen(8080);

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
    socket.on('my event', function (msg) {
        console.log("DATA!!!");
    });
});
```

**I could not find a way to require without a full path**

Client code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <title>Hello World!</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <script src="http://localhost:8080/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:8080');
            $("#button").click(function() {
                socket.emit('my event' ,"Hello World!");
            })
        })
    </script>
</head>

<body>
<button type="button" id='button'>Send Message</button>
</body>

</html>
```

Modules versions:

```
C:\Users\shlomis>npm ls
mukhin_chat@0.0.1 C:\Users\shlomis
├─┬ express@2.5.9
│ ├─┬ connect@1.8.6
│ │ └── formidable@1.0.9
│ ├── mime@1.2.4
│ ├── mkdirp@0.3.0
│ └── qs@0.4.2
└─┬ socket.io@0.9.5
  ├── policyfile@0.0.4
  ├── redis@0.6.7
  └─┬ socket.io-client@0.9.5
    ├─┬ active-x-obfuscator@0.0.1
    │ └── zeparser@0.0.5
    ├── uglify-js@1.2.5
    ├─┬ ws@0.4.12
    │ ├── commander@0.5.2
    │ └── options@0.0.3
    └── xmlhttprequest@1.2.2
```

Node log:

```
C:\Users\shlomis>node C:\dev\wamp\www\AR\js\videoServer.js
   info  - socket.io started
   debug - served static content /socket.io.js
   debug - client authorized
   info  - handshake authorized 17502185141066845391
   debug - setting request GET /socket.io/1/websocket/17502185141066845391
   debug - set heartbeat interval for client 17502185141066845391
   debug - client authorized for
   debug - websocket writing 1::
   debug - setting request GET /socket.io/1/xhr-polling/17502185141066845391?t=1334041653716
   debug - setting poll timeout
   debug - discarding transport
   debug - cleared heartbeat interval for client 17502185141066845391
```

chrome WS request (101 Switching Protocols):
[image]

chrome XHR request:
[image]

**Update :** Iv'e added

```
socket.on('connect', function () {
     console.log("connected");
});
```

It never fires on chrome.

So what could be wrong? please help out :)

Comment: I've got exactly the same issue... socket.emit('hello') on the client works in safari, but not in firefox or chrome... Security restriction maybe? Or possibly a socket.io bug.

Comment: Could it be the `same-origin` policy, since the failure happens only when XHR is used? Try making a simple XHR to localhost:different-port-than-served-page, see if you get any security exceptions.

Comment: NO security issues, I now use http://faye.jcoglan.com/node.html (faye) for sockets over node JS and it works fine ... looks like a socket.io bug to me.

Comment: Oh, I got the same problem :(... It works with almost everyone else but me.

Comment: Any solutions to this problem? I am getting the same problem.. :(

Comment: My solution was to switch to http://faye.jcoglan.com/node.html

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're using the wrong socket.io.js file for the client?

https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io-client/tree/master/dist

you should use these files in a folder where you have your client-side stuff on, ie: 
`../js/socket.io.min.js`

About the require problem, are you using npm? go into the nodeJS project folder and run the following:

`npm install socket.io`

this should install to the `node_modules` folder inside your project folder and by doing a `require('socket.io');` you should be able to access the module.

if this isn't working, you probably have a corrupt installation of node.

PS: Are you using the same port for the files? you seem to be looking for the socket.io file on port 8080 and then connecting to nodeJS on port 8080 for socket connections...

try using another port?

Comment: Even I'm having the same problem. It does not work on Firefox and Chrome but it works just fine on IE. Please help.